# Повторяющееся море

Tags: веб-программирование, дизайн

Добрый день. Делаю рыболовный интернет магазин. В шапку хочу вставить море, чтобы получилось что-то такого плана

[image: img]

Текстуру моря я выбрал, но при повторе очень заметны стыки. Единственное что пришло в голову - это сделать длинное изображение и замазать аккуратно эти стыки. Но при этом размер моего моря получается около 2мб. Посоветуйте как мне быть? Может кто-то сталкивался с текстурой моря, которая хорошо стыкуется при повторе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать фон из нескольких накладывающихся png волн кластеров волн. На примере можно сказать, что есть усредненный сплошной фон, и есть отдельные фигуры волн - чуть светлее, и чуть темнее основного тона. Вот их группы и надо выделить в 3-5 отдельных png'шек.

Если их сделать разной ширины, причем соблюсти взаимную простоту чисел их ширины, получится вообще весьма неповторяющийся фон. Подробнее: «[Принцип цикады](http://habrahabr.ru/post/117160/)», и вот [пример с водной поверхностью](http://designfestival.com/cicada/break-it-down/?id=66), не совсем то, но близко.

Comment: Вы не первый советуете принцип цикады. Но я не совсем понимаю о чем идет речь... 
Мне нужно сделать голубоватый фон, вставить светлые/темные волны и клепануть около 5 таких небольших изображений. А потом задать фон шапки по такому принципу: background-image: url(29-a.png),url(37-a.png), url(53-a.png); ???

Comment: Ссылки открывали?

Comment: Конечно да!

Answer (score 3):

Создайте пяток PNGшек с морем и полупрозрачными краями. Каждая PNGшка - вертикальная, шириной в 1-3волны, высотой во весь сайт. 
Нафигачьте их в подложку в дивах, рэндомно.
Состыкуются они сами.